# How to declare a generic function returning a type satisfying multiple constraints in F#?

Tags: f#, generics

What I am trying to write:

```
type A() =
    interface IX with ...
    interface IY with ...

type B() =
    interface IX with ...
    interface IY with ...

let mk t : 'T when 'T :> IX and 'T :> IY =
    match t with
    | Choice1 -> new A()
    | Choice2 -> new B()
```

Note the type constraints on the return type of mk. It does not compile though, the compiler complains that it can't convert A and B to 'T.

Comment: Just for fun, compare the equivalent code in C# http://pastebin.com/daFFKTwB. You're trying to return a concrete type of 'T, but you don't use that type in the rest of your function -- you try to return a concrete A or B, and the type-checker can't figure out what you really intended.

Comment: More to consider: if I write `let x, y = mk Choice1, mk Choice2`, what types do `x` and `y` have?

Comment: Right, I was thinking that "A is-a T" and "B is-a T", but that's only correct when these statements are considered independently. Tomas' solution relaxes the requirement that T be the same in both cases, and kvb's solution introduces a new type T that satisfies both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constraint is okay, but the problem is that there is no type that would satisfy the constraint and that would be a supertype of both `A` and `B`.

The `match` construct needs to return the same type from both of the branches, so you'd need to add upcast (`:>`) to some type such that the conversion works for both of the branches. The type could be either `IX` or `IY`, but that wouldn't satisfy the constraint.

This would be possible only if .NET allowed you to write something like `IX+IY` which would mean a type that implements both of the interfaces. Then you would also be able to work with values of this type e.g.:

```
let (a:IX+IY) = new A()  // This isn't supported
```

I think that the best solution is to simply return a tuple `IX * IY` containing two times the same instance, but represented as different type. Here the constriant you wrote can be quite useful:

```
// Type: 'a -> IX * IY when 'a :> IX and 'a :> IY
let asTuple a = (a :> IX, a :> IY)

let mk t = 
  match t with 
  | Choice1Of2() -> new A() |> asTuple
  | Choice2Of2() -> new B() |> asTuple
```

Answer (score 7):

If you control types `A` and `B`, then the simplest solution would be to define

```
type IXY =
  inherit IX
  inherit IY
```

and then have `A` and `B` inherit `IXY`, and `mk` would just return an `IXY` rather than a generic type (which doesn't really make sense anyway, even without the constraints).

Comment: i agree with kvb, this is the most common approach to this sort of thing